# Install4j: The directory picker screen sets wrong default value when run in console mode

Tags: install4j

I want to set the default value of a directory in the directory picker screen to empty(I do this by setting the variable to a empty String). This works fine when I run the installer in GUI mode, but when I run it in console mode the install4j installer sets the default value to the install4j tmp directory(eg: /home/ubuntu/xxxx-xxx1.2.3-linux-x64.bin.2677.dir). 
Is there a way to make this consistent across console and gui?
install4j: 5.1.15

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a "Directory selection" screen or with a "Directory chooser" form component. If the "Initial directory" property is empty, console mode suggests an empty directory for me (install4j 6.0.4)

Comment: I am on install4j 5.1.15, may be its a bug in the previous version?

Comment: It could be, have you tried it with the latest version?